# The stopped process $(M'_n, n \in \mathbb{N})$ with $M'_n := M_{T \wedge n}$ is a martingale

Tags: probability-theory, martingales, stopping-times

I'm tryin to verify that the following stopped process is a martingale, i.e.,

> **Theorem** Let $(M_n, n \in \mathbb{N})$ be a martingale and $T$ a stopping time with respect to a filtration $(\mathcal{F}_n, n \in \mathbb{N})$. Then the stopped process $(M'_n, n \in \mathbb{N})$ with $M'_n := M_{T \wedge n}$ where $T \wedge n := \min \{T, n\}$ is also a martingale with respect to $(\mathcal{F}_n, n \in \mathbb{N})$.

Could you have a check on my below attempt?

---

**Proof**  We have $M'_n$ is $\mathcal F_{T \wedge n}$-measurable. We have $T \wedge n \le n$, so $\mathcal F_{T \wedge n} \subset \mathcal F_n$. It follows that $M'_n$ is $\mathcal F_n$-measurable. We have $M'_n$ is integrable because
$$
\mathbb E [|M'_n|] = \mathbb E \left [ \sum_{k=0}^{n-1} |M_k| 1_{\{T=k\}} + |M_n| 1_{\{T\ge n\}} \right] \le \sum_{k=0}^n \mathbb E [|M_k|] < \infty.
$$

Notice that $\{T \ge n+1\} \in \mathcal F_n$. We have
$$
\begin{align}
\mathbb E [M'_{n+1} | \mathcal F_{n}] &= \mathbb E [ M_{T \wedge (n+1)} | \mathcal F_{n}] \\
&= \mathbb E \left [ \sum_{k=0}^{n} M_k 1_{\{T=k\}} + M_{n+1} 1_{\{T\ge n+1\}} \bigg \lvert \mathcal F_n \right] \\
&=  \sum_{k=0}^{n} \mathbb E \left [  M_k 1_{\{T=k\}}  \bigg \lvert \mathcal F_n \right] + \mathbb E [M_{n+1} 1_{\{T\ge n+1\}} | \mathcal F_n] \\
&=  \sum_{k=0}^{n} M_k 1_{\{T=k\}} + \mathbb E [M_{n+1}  | \mathcal F_n] 1_{\{T\ge n+1\}} \\
&=  \sum_{k=0}^{n} M_k 1_{\{T=k\}} + M_{n} 1_{\{T\ge n+1\}} \\
&= M_{T \wedge n}.
\end{align}
$$

This completes the proof.

Comment: This looks correct.  Is there any reason you think it's not?

Comment: @user6247850 Thank you so much for your verification! This is because my lecture note said that the proof is by the optional stopping theorem. I'm not sure if my simpler approach is fine.

Comment: I'm a little confused by that because, to me, this theorem *is* the optional stopping theorem.  Oh well, either way, the proof looks good.

Comment: @user6247850 You can find that statement in page 73 of the [note](https://ipgold.epfl.ch/~leveque/Lecture_Notes/APA_lecture_notes_1920.pdf)...